# Where to run Jazzy in my Development Pod Document tree

Tags: swift3, cocoapods, jazzy

I can't get jazzy working with my private CocoaPod. I don't understand where in the Document Tree of my CocoaPod I need to run the Jazzy command? I always get this error:

Running xcodebuild

Could not parse compiler arguments from `xcodebuild` output.

Please confirm that `xcodebuild` is building a Swift module.

Saved `xcodebuild` log file: /var/folders/wm/ypqvslpj03s4lkgk9kw4f03h0000gn/T/xcodebuild-4B0909ED-AD27-4C5A-B461-388EEE1BA6A9.log

Failed to generate documentation
    from /Users/pascalvanderlocht/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/jazzy-0.7.3/lib/jazzy/sourcekitten.rb:147:in `run_sourcekitten'
    from /Users/pascalvanderlocht/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/jazzy-0.7.3/lib/jazzy/doc_builder.rb:65:in`block in build'
    from /Users/pascalvanderlocht/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/jazzy-0.7.3/lib/jazzy/doc_builder.rb:63:in `chdir'
    from /Users/pascalvanderlocht/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/jazzy-0.7.3/lib/jazzy/doc_builder.rb:63:in`build'
    from /Users/pascalvanderlocht/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/jazzy-0.7.3/bin/jazzy:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/pascalvanderlocht/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/jazzy:22:in`load'
    from /Users/pascalvanderlocht/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/jazzy:22:in `<main>'
    from /Users/pascalvanderlocht/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in`eval'
    from /Users/pascalvanderlocht/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `'

Where in my CocoaPod Directory do I need to run the command?
Any help appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

This is a little late, but there is a `jazzy --podspec <Your Pod>.podspec` command

Comment: I'd say so. I think jazzy can take all the information it needs out of a podspec, so it doesn't matter how the surrounding repository is stored. Have you tried with a private CocoaPod?